# Why table with z-index is not showing over others?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two tables one of them is shown and the other is hidden.
When the page load I show the other using jQuery and it shows perfectly but the problem is that I want the hidden table to be shown over the other I used `z-index` but the table still shows next to each others.

```
<table border="1" class="mask">
    <tr>
        <td>this table should be over the background</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="mask1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>this table should be in the background</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.mask {
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        get = $(document).find('.mask');
        $(get).show();
        $(get).css({"background-color": "red","z-index": "999"});
    },5000);
});
```

I show the table and the background takes the red color but the `z-index` does not work as it should and the table did not show over any other thing.
Is there something missing?

Comment: You need to add `position` otherwise `z-index` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. If you do nothing to move the elements out of their normal flow position, then they will appear one after the other and you couldn't tell if they were at different `z-index`s
2. The `z-index` property only applies to elements with `position` set to something other than `static` (which is the default)

Adding `position: relative; top: -20px;` would cause them to overlap. You need to come up with positioning rules that put them where you actually want them.

If you want their top left corners to overlap, then:

1. Put both elements in a container (a div will do)
2. Set `position: relative` on that div (to establish a positioning context)
3. Set `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` on (at least) the table you are setting the `z-index` on

Answer (score 1):

A `z-index` property has no effect on elements statically positioned.
so try giving `position: relative` to your first table

Comment: it is not working with relative. I tried absolute and it is work.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `z-index` property to take effect the element must be positioned meaning its `position` style is set to relative, absolute or fixed.